# Trema(ruby)で仮想hostの作成時のエラー

Tags: ruby, centos

Trema( https://yasuhito.github.io/trema-book/ )のサイトを参考に6章までできたのですが、gitコマンドでclone( https://github.com/trema/patch_panel.git )して、bundle installをしたあとに実行してみるとhost関係の以下のようなエラーが発生します。

```
[root@localhost patch_panel]# ./bin/trema run ./lib/patch_panel.rb -c patch_panel.conf
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/phut-0.7.5/lib/phut/shell_runner.rb:5:in `sh': sudo ip link add name patch_panel_1 type veth peer name host1 failed. (RuntimeError)
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/phut-0.7.5/lib/phut/virtual_link.rb:99:in `add'
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/phut-0.7.5/lib/phut/virtual_link.rb:67:in `run'
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/phut-0.7.5/lib/phut/virtual_link.rb:15:in `each'
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/phut-0.7.5/lib/phut/virtual_link.rb:15:in `each'
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/phut-0.7.5/lib/phut/configuration.rb:44:in `block in run'
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/phut-0.7.5/lib/phut/configuration.rb:43:in `each'
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/phut-0.7.5/lib/phut/configuration.rb:43:in `run'
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/trema-0.9.0/lib/trema/command.rb:110:in `block in start_phut'
```

環境はCentOS 7です。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

```
sh': sudo ip link add name patch_panel_1 type veth peer name host1 failed. (RuntimeError)
```

上記エラーは、シェルコマンドの実行エラーと思います。
試しに、ターミナルから手動でエラーのあったコマンドを実行し、表示されるエラーメッセージを確認してください。

```
sudo ip link add name patch_panel_1 type veth peer name host1
```

表示されるエラー内容によって対応がかわると思いますが、もし、すでに`patch_panel_1`が存在するという意味のエラーであれば、`sudo ip link delete ...`などにより手動で削除してから`trema`を実行すると良いと思います。

Comment: 無事解決できました。ありがとうございました。